# MySQL multiple where clauses generated dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

So the user can choose how many categories he wants to filter a list by

When there's only one item selected everything is fine:

```
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id, a.PAnr, b.family, b.articlenr, b.ratio, a.oiltype, a.oiltemp
        FROM testdata_test a, testdata_gear b
        WHERE a.id = b.test_id  AND b.family = 'R660' 
        ORDER BY a.PAnr desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

But when the user adds more:

```
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id, a.PAnr, b.family, b.articlenr, b.ratio, a.oiltype, a.oiltemp
        FROM testdata_test a, testdata_gear b
        WHERE a.id = b.test_id  AND b.family = 'R540' OR  b.family = 'R660' 
        ORDER BY a.PAnr desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

I get around 4 million hits when the table without the AND part is around 4000. If the user selects another one theres around 8 million hits.
What am I missing?

Comment: What were you missing?  Parentheses.

Comment: Yeah pretty much @DanBracuk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to this, your query will not run OR statement as expected,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id, a.PAnr, b.family, b.articlenr, 
        b.ratio, a.oiltype, a.oiltemp
        FROM testdata_test a, testdata_gear b
        WHERE a.id = b.test_id  AND (b.family = 'R540' OR  b.family = 'R660')
        ORDER BY a.PAnr desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

Or

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.id, a.PAnr, b.family, b.articlenr, 
        b.ratio, a.oiltype, a.oiltemp
        FROM testdata_test a, testdata_gear b
        WHERE a.id = b.test_id  AND b.family IN ('R540','R660')
        ORDER BY a.PAnr desc
        LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `and` and `or` clauses without `()`, so you're effectively running:

```
WHERE ((a.id = b.test_id) AND (b.family = 'R540')) 
   OR (b.family = 'R660')
```

Note how the `()` have been positioned.

You probably want

```
WHERE (a.id = b.test_id) AND (b.family IN ('R540', 'R660'))
```